# Which guns can shoot through walls?

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

Excluding snipers, are there any guns which can shoot through walls?

Answer (score 2):

This is dependent on the gun you're using, the modifications you have on the weapon, and the wall you're shooting. Of course, a pistol isn't going to go through cinderblocks and even an SMG won't, but if you put the full metal jacket(FMJ) onto the weapon in the loadout screen, you will be able to penetrate material that might not be penetrated usually.

Comment: I also thought range is calculated in?